# Want to show these orders in Firebase recyclerview but getting only one order detail at a time and i m getting refernce to orders node only

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**orders node having phone numbers**

[image]

```
orders_ref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("orders");


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminOrders> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminOrders>()
            .setQuery(orders_ref,AdminOrders.class)
            .build();
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: But its not working for my only displaying one order and not the all orders why so??